# OpenCV build Error - MSB3073 The command "setlocal

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am trying to install the OpenCV from source using CMake. When I try to build the `ALL_BUILD` using release, everything succeeds. When i build the `INSTALL` i get error

> MSB3073 The command "setlocal

Output is like this:

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
2>Done building project "INSTALL.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 89 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have looked through some forums, and they said I needed to open it up with admin privilege's, I have tried all that, I tried installing OpenCV on `D:` drive, where I got same error and now I tried installing it on `C:` drive where I get the same error. Folders path is not in `Program Files` its in `Users`. I have also pointed to correct folder for `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.

Comment: The error message should be in the output just prior to the output you've posted. There should be more detail on what exactly went wrong. alternatively you could run the command mentioned in the output yourself from the command line (`cmake -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake` run inside the correct dir). CMake installation can include the execution of a script which could result in an issue even if you install to a directory where you've got all necessary rights.

Comment: However just to confirm: You did start Visual Studio with admin privileges and/or executed the build from a command line with those rights.

Comment: I have tried running the CMD with admin privileges, and ran the command and received this error `CMake Error at modules/python3/cmake_install.cmake:44 (file):
  file cannot create directory: C:/Program
  Files/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0/Lib/site-packages/cv2.
  Maybe need administrative privileges.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/cmake_install.cmake:91 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:129 (include)`